# Sort 2 String[] arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I sort two arrays in relation to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213493/can-i-sort-two-lists-in-relation-to-each-other)

I have 2 two `String[]` arrays. I want to sort 2nd array with index same with the 1st array.

```java
private void checkDatabase(String keyword, String origins) {
    List<RSList> rslist = db.getAllRSListsByType(keyword);

    total = rslist.toArray().length;

    String[] titlearray = new String[total];
    String[] distance = new String[total];

    int i = 0;
    for (RSList cn : rslist) {
        titlearray[i] = cn.getName();
        String origin = origins;
        String destination = cn.getGlat() + "," + cn.getGlon();
        distance[i] = checkDataToGoogle(origin, destination);
        Log.i("Name: ", distance[i]);
        i++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(distance);
    filldata(titlearray, distance);
}
```

I want to make index of `titlearray` same with `distance` array, I already sort the `distance` array first, but I don't know how to make order of `titlearray` same with `distance`.

Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: Using standard Java sorting you will need to create (or find) a suitable Composite Type and then either implement `Comparable` or create a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: Pls see [Sort one List<> based on another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14227784), diff language though

Comment: @pst One suggestion that would apply is to rethink/rework the data structures if possible to unify the 2 arrays into 1..

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839915/sorting-a-list-based-on-another-lists-values-java , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689455/sort-an-object-by-an-other-one?rq=1